# How do I filter SO questions to tags I'm interested in?

Tags: support

When I go to the Stack Overflow main page, I want to only see questions marked with tags I'm interested in. Surely this is really easy, but I can't work out how to do it. What do I do?

Answer (score 3):

Just add the interesting tags to your "Favorite Tags" list and the tags you want to ignore to the Ignored Tags list:
[image: tags screenshot]

You can add tags by either typing in the textbox (there is auto complete) or by clicking the star icon in each tag "cloud" opened when hovering over it.

Having this, the default view in SO main page which is called "interesting" questions will show questions that may be of interest to you based on your history and tag preferences which means all the questions tagged by any tag in your Favorite Tags list, plus tags of questions you have answered in the past.

Comment: This just hasn't worked. I've added 'sql' and 'sql server' to my favourite tags, clicked on 'Interesting questions' and the fifth question has the tags 'iphone', 'cocoa-touch' and 'mkmapview'. I've never answered questions about these things.

Comment: Weird.. anyhow that's the best we have right now - not sure how the algorithm for "interesting questions" works.

Comment: Okay, cool - but we can conclude it's not based purely on favourite tags. Thank you.

Comment: Not purely, right. You can add tags to the Ignored list though, eventually you'll stay only with the tags you really want.

Answer (score 2):

The only reliable way I have found is to save a link like this to your browser favourites:

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle%20or%20oracle10g%20or%20oracle11g%20or%20plsql%20or%20apex%20or%20oracle-apex

It isn't ideal, as it isn't available from other PCs (though of course could save via Delicious or similar).

This is probably a deliberate policy to encourage us all to look at questions outside our narrow preferences!

Comment: Yes, possibly! Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

[Stackexchange favourite tags filter](https://stackexchange.com/filters/19943/favorite-tags)

You can even specify your own custom filters.

Comment: I have already done this, but when I go to the SO homepage, I still see questions that aren't in my filters.

Comment: The filters work on the Stackexchange site, not on Stackoverflow. If you follow the link, you will see the new questions with your tags.

Comment: Yes, when I go to Stack Exchange - My Filters, I see only the filtered list (although strictly speaking this doesn't answer my question since I was talking about Stack Overflow specifically). Maybe I just need to update my bookmark to show this page, but I don't see my SO profile details at the top...

Comment: I don't think there is another way to get only the tags you are interested in directly on SO. The interesting questions are a mix of your fav-tags and other questions.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you for the clarification.